# Python odd pymysql error. Can't figure it out

Tags: python, mysql

I keep getting this sql error. I can't seem to diagnose the problem. Any help would be great.

From what I can tell, the trouble spot is 2nd update to the mySQL field. If I'm not mistaken, I was not getting the error when I only had the first one. Is a connection commit/close thing? The error seems oddly vague.

Here is the trouble code:

```
for item in to_render:
    def sequence_and_encode():
        print("RENDERING SEQUENCES.")
        with conn.cursor() as c:
            sql = "UPDATE test_database.encode_queue SET status=%s WHERE UID=%s"
            c.execute(sql, ('rendering', uid, ))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        map_results = pool.map_async(subprocess.check_output, sequence_all).get(9999999)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        anim_name = str(uid)        
        encode_type = (
            "encode_templates/prores_hq.sh " + "'" + anim_name + "' '" + sequence_creation_temp + "' '" + videos_final + "' '" + scripts_final + "'")
        output = subprocess.check_output(encode_type, shell=True)
        with conn.cursor() as c:
            sql = "UPDATE test_database.encode_queue SET status=%s WHERE UID=%s"
            c.execute(sql, ('complete', uid, ))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        gc.collect()
    sequence_and_encode()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/marcleonard/PycharmProjects/Creating Animation/pickup_encodes.py", line 116, in <module>
    sequence_and_encode()                      #comment out to disable render #THIS WAS NOT INDENTED (to this point....)
  File "/Users/marcleonard/PycharmProjects/Creating Animation/pickup_encodes.py", line 112, in sequence_and_encode
    c.execute(sql, ('complete', uid, ))
  File "/Users/marcleonard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/marcleonard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Users/marcleonard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 834, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/Users/marcleonard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1033, in _execute_command
    raise err.InterfaceError("(0, '')")
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')
```

Comment: Could it be because you've already closed the connection before via `conn.close()`?

Comment: You have a great observation from @alecxe - remove the `conn.close()`.  It kinda makes sense that executes on a closed connection don't work. Can you confirm this works so alecxe can make this an answer and others won't waste their time pondering the question?

Comment: Ok, that was indeed the problem. However, I'm still unclear why it didn't work. Once I use the second `with conn.cursor() as c:` doesn't that mean I have opened the connection back up?